# how to find the Min value among multiple col

Tags: sql, database, min

i have in my DB 3 col and i want to find a single value among all of them as explaind here: table name:MyTable

```
-----------------------------
--id-- col1-- col2-- col3-
-----------------------------
   1     200    300     400 
   2     100    150     300
   3     800    102     20
   4     80     80       0
```

i want the result out of col1 col2 col3 to be = 0 , which is the min value among them.
is it possible !!!!

my try:

```
select Min(col1, col2 , col3) as Tablemin
from MyTable
```

Comment: Is it something you could easily do in code once you get the results back? Do you have to do it in SQL?

Answer (score 6):

ANSI SQL:

```
select min(col)
from
(
    select col1 [col] from MyTable
    union all
    select col2 from MyTable
    union all
    select col3 from MyTable
)t
```

Comment: You can use just UNION, no need for UNION ALL.

Comment: You can use UNION, but better use UNION ALL, it's faster.

Answer (score 2):

If it is MySQL or Oracle, there is `LEAST()` function:

```
SELECT LEAST(MIN(col1), MIN(col2), MIN(col3))
       AS MinOfAllColumns
FROM MyTable
```

Then, there is the `CASE` statement which can be used in most RDBMSs:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(col1) <= MIN(col2) AND MIN(col1) <= MIN(col3) 
                THEN MIN(col1)
            WHEN MIN(col2) <= MIN(col3)
                THEN MIN(col2)
                ELSE MIN(col3)            
       END 
       AS MinOfAllColumns
FROM MyTable
```

---

This can also work but it's hard to get other fields with the `UNION` approach:

```
SELECT MIN(col) AS MinOfAllColumns
FROM 
  ( SELECT MIN(col1) AS col
    FROM MyTable
  UNION
    SELECT MIN(col2)
    FROM MyTable
  UNION
    SELECT MIN(col3)
    FROM MyTable
  ) AS tmp
```

Comment: i tried it ,but i received an error says can't recognize the syntax am working in sql server business intelligence is there a proper syntax for this app to build my query .

Comment: @polishchuk: I know but it's not the same. You UNION, then group to find MIN.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to display min is:

```
string val = textBox2.Text;
DataSet ds;
con.Open();
string str = "SELECT * FROM Add_Rooms WHERE Price >= @price";
cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", val);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Add_Rooms");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "Add_Rooms";
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQLITE the answer is as simple as:

```
SELECT MIN(MIN(col1), MIN(col2), MIN(col3)) FROM MyTable;
```