# Standard SQL to replace GREATEST() in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I have a MySQL query that uses the `GREATEST()` function, and I want to rewrite it in standard ANSI SQL to run on others databases. I know GREATEST is supported by most SQL databases, but I'm probably going to run the query in Hive, which supports things like CASE but not GREATEST.

Can anyone think of an elegant way to rewrite this query without using `GREATEST()`?

Thanks!

```
select 
greatest(play,play_25,play_50,play_75,play_100) as play,
greatest(play_25,play_50,play_75,play_100) as play_25,
greatest(play_50,play_75,play_100) as play_50,
greatest(play_75,play_100) as play_75,
play_100 as play_100 
from video_buckets
```

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717127/how-to-find-the-min-value-among-multiple-col

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, although I am not sure if you could call it 'elegant':

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN play_25 > play THEN play_25 ELSE play END AS play,
  play_25,
  play_50,
  play_75,
  play_100
FROM (
  SELECT
    play,
    CASE WHEN play_50 > play_25 THEN play_50 ELSE play_25 END AS play_25,
    play_50,
    play_75,
    play_100
  FROM (
    SELECT
      play,
      play_25,
      CASE WHEN play_75 > play_50 THEN play_75 ELSE play_50 END AS play_50,
      play_75,
      play_100
    FROM (
      SELECT
        play,
        play_25,
        play_50,
        CASE WHEN play_100 > play_75 THEN play_100 ELSE play_75 END AS play_75,
        play_100
      FROM video_buckets
    ) s
  ) s
) s
```

Comment: I think it's elegant enough for my purposes, and should work in Hive. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This won't work in MySQL but [validates as Full SQL-92](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser92/index.tml#parser)

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(c)
        FROM   (VALUES(play),
                      (play_25),
                      (play_50),
                      (play_75),
                      (play_100)) T (c))  AS play,
       (SELECT MAX(c)
        FROM   (VALUES (play_25),
                       (play_50),
                       (play_75),
                       (play_100)) T (c)) AS play_25
FROM   video_buckets
```

Comment: How about your [other idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766921/updating-row-in-table-based-on-sub-query-on-same-table/7774262#7774262), would *it* work in MySQL?

Comment: @AndriyM - No. MySQL doesn't support these references to columns from the outer query in a derived table. AFAIK the derived table needs to be static throughout the query.

Comment: I guess this will not work with MySQL. Perhaps it would be worth trying to rewrite this using UNION.

Comment: @Karolis - I've tried before and MySQL still doesn't like it! Also that would need a `FROM` clause for each bit of the `UNION` to validate as standard SQL.